# Android Studio: Extract method shortcut '⌥+⌘+M' (Option-Command-M) no longer working (macOS Mojave)

Tags: macos, android-studio, keyboard-shortcuts, android-studio-3.3

I've been using the following keyboard shortcut to extract a method in Android Studio:

<kbd>⌥</kbd>+<kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>M</kbd> (Option-Command-M)

A couple of days ago this stopped working and I can't figure out why. Is anyone else experiencing this issue? Does anyone have a solution?

I do realise that this shortcut is a macOS shortcut to minimise all windows of an application but not even that happens.

I'm on macOS Mojave (10.14.3) with Android Studio 3.3.2 but my co-worker has the same issue on Android studio 3.1.2.

Comment: May be you are searching for keyboard shortcut setting. try : https://imgur.com/l4PSv6w

Comment: @VishvaDave I do know where to customise shortcuts but since I'm using Android studio on multiple machines, I'd rather keep the original mapping. If all else fails I will of course change the shortcut on all my development machines.

Comment: @natronite I can test this out in a few hours on my Mac device - I had a lot of trouble with Android Studio 3+ after updating

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After several days I finally found out what was going on. It turns out the Time Doctor app ate my keyboard shortcut even though I don't have disabled the shortcuts in said app. After stopping Time Doctor everything is back to normal.

Comment: Thanks for coming back and reporting this.  So many people don't.

Answer (score 1):

Did you try to find what this shortcut is doing currently?

You can go to
`Preferences` -> `Keymap` -> and after click `loupe/lense` you can click your combination  <kbd>⌥</kbd>+<kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>M</kbd> ) to find where (to which action) it is assigned currently.

[image]

On the list (after search) at least one position should appear.

Comment: I checked before posting the question of course. I couldn't even input the shortcut into the search.